# d3 real time line chart with labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am creating the line chart with the following http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Now I want to display the value of last data on line chart curve i.e the new value adding into the chart.so I tried this code it added the label but when new data is added the chart doesnot get updated.
NOTE:My data length is 13.I am trying to show last data value only.

```
   svg.append("text")
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .style("fill", "red")
     .attr({
         'x':x(12),
          'y': y(data[12])
      })
      .text(data[12]);
```

Comment: Can you please put this up on fiddle.

Comment: Thanks I have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you solved the issue, here is a code snippet just in case anyone else is looking (since I was in the middle of posting when you added your comment).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
 }
 .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }
 .text {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var numPoints = 40,
  random = d3.random.normal(0, .2),
  data = d3.range(numPoints).map(random);
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 40},
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, numPoints - 1])
  .range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);
 var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
  .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));
 var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
 var textFormat = d3.format(".3f");
 var lastPoint = svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("class", "text")
  .attr({
   'x':x(numPoints-1),
   'y': y(data[numPoints-1])
  })
  .text(textFormat(data[numPoints-1]));

 tick();

 function tick() {
  // push a new data point onto the back
  data.push(random());
  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
  path
   .attr("d", line)
   .attr("transform", null)
   .transition()
   .duration(500)
   .ease("linear")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
   .each("start", function () {
    lastPoint
     .text(textFormat(data[numPoints-2]))
     .attr({
      'x':x(numPoints-2),
      'y': y(data[numPoints-2])
     })
     .attr("transform", null)
     .transition()
      .duration(500)
     .ease("linear")
     .text(textFormat(data[numPoints-1]))
     .attr({
      'x':x(numPoints-1),
      'y': y(data[numPoints-1])
     })
   })
   .each("end", tick);

  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();

 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here the value is going out of svg content .How can we solve this issue?

Comment: @Ankita - the value isn't going out of the content on my pc, but if you want to ensure that it remains inside the svg you can left justify the text, position the text so it doesn't fall outside the svg bounds, or increase the width of the margins to account for the text.